# не выводится динамический массив си++

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, матрицы, динамические-массивы

все работает, кроме вывода последней матрицы "transpose dinMass:", она просто не выводится

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

void transpose(int matrix[4][4]){

    int t;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        for(int j = i; j < 4; ++j){

            t = matrix[i][j];
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
            matrix[j][i] = t;
        }
    }
}
void transpose1(int(* matrix)[4]){

    int t;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        for(int j = i; j < 4; ++j){

            t = matrix[i][j];
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
            matrix[j][i] = t;
        }
    }
}
void transpose2 (int **matrix, size_t m,size_t n){

    int t;
    for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        for(int j = i; j < n; ++j){

            t = matrix[i][j];
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
            matrix[j][i] = t;
        }
    }
}



int main(){

    const int n(4), m(4);

    int **dinMass = new int*[4];

    int statMass[n][m];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            int value = 1+rand() % 11;
            statMass[i][j] = value;

            **dinMass = value;
        }
    }

    cout << "Adresses:" << endl;
    cout << "statMass = " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++){
             cout << setw(10) << statMass << " ";
         }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "dinMass = " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++){
             cout << setw(10) << dinMass << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    //---------------------------------------------

    transpose(statMass);

       cout << "transpose 1 statMass:" << endl;
       for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
           for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
               cout << setw(10) << statMass[i][j];
               cout << endl;
       }

     transpose1(statMass);
     cout << "transpose 2 statMass:" << endl;
     for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
         for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
             cout << setw(10) << statMass[i][j];
             cout << endl;
     }

     //---------------------------------------------

     transpose2 (dinMass, 4, 4);

       cout << "transpose dinMass:" << endl;
       for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
           for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
               cout << setw(10) << dinMass[i][j];
               cout << endl;
       }

       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
           delete[] dinMass[i];
       delete[] dinMass;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так давайте посмотрим, что вы делаете...

```
int **dinMass = new int*[4];
```

Выдедили массив указателей, указывающих "в никуда" (с мусорными значениями) и

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++){
        ......            
        **dinMass = value;
    }
}
```

И nxm раз записываете значение по (мусорному) адресу, хранящемуся в первом указателе.

Понятно, что у вас ничего не работает... Нет как такового массива!

Вот если бы код выглядел так...

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    dinMass[i] = new int[m];
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++){
        ......            
        dinMass[i][j] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за правку, но выводится почему-то все равно мусор, хотя dinMass же инициализирован рандомными значениями

Comment: Проверьте, что у вас не так по сравнению с исправленным согласно моим замечанием кодом: https://ideone.com/fSD2il  Как видите, выводится полне нормальная матрица, как и `statMass` после первого транспонирования.

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Ну, если все получилось - принимайте ответ (птичка слева).

Comment: Можете посмотреть еще тут - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138290/195342